# Compose parts in MEF

Tags: .net, ioc-container, mef, composition

Consider the following situation:

```
[Export]
class A { }

class B 
{
  [Import]
  private A a;
}

// Instantiates class B.
class C 
{   
  public C(Type type){ /*Instantiate Class B here.*/}

  public void PerfomOperationUsingClassB() { }
}

class D
{
  void Initialize()
  {
    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(A)));
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    // Is there any way to compose A with B?

    C c = new C(typeof(B));
    c.PerfomOperationUsingClassB();
  }
}
```

Problem: I have an access to class "A" and "B" but class "C" is located in the assembly that I can't modify (thus can't modify the class "C"). Is there any way to compose "A" and "B"?

Comment: Gah! There is code formatting! Cleaning up that unfsmy mess of `<br>` and `&nbsp;` is not fun.

Comment: Do you want to eliminate usage of class C, or is the call to c.PerformOperationUsingClassB mandatory?

Comment: Can you import into private members with MEF now?

Comment: Oh, cool! I must try out the new bits then!

Comment: @Matt New Bits? Mef shipped with .Net 4

Comment: for some reason I had thought that it can't compose private members... but just tried it and yes, you can... my bad!

Comment: @Matt - Although you can compose private members, it has to do so via reflection, which enforces a requirement of full trust. If you can develop to avoid composing private fields/properties I'd recommend you do so. Besides, with private values being composed, how can you test your code correctly?

Comment: yeah, I realise its a bad practice... private means private :) I just thought MEF didn't support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without access to whatever the constructor of `C` is doing, you pretty much out of luck. The constructor of `C` seems to want to initialise an instance of `B` using the type itself... does it provide any mechanism of intercepting the initialisation of `B` within `C`?

If `C` were to accept an instance of `B` instead, you could easily just pass in a composed instance of `B` into the constructor. If you wanted to export the closed type, `C`, you could do something like:

```
public class MefAdapter<T, TExport>
{
  private readonly Func<T, TExport> _factory = CreateFactory();
  private readonly T _arg;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public MefAdapter(T arg)
  {
    _arg = arg;
  }

  [Export]
  public TExport Export
  {
    get { return _factory(_arg); }
  }

  internal static Func<T, TExport> CreateFactory()
  {
    var tArg = typeof(T);
    var tExport = typeof(TExport);

    var arg = Expression.Parameter(tArg, "arg");
    var ctor = tExport.GetConstructor(new[] { tArg });
    var ctorExp = Expression.New(ctor, arg);

    return Expression.Lamda<Func<T, TExport>>(ctorExp, arg).Compile();
  }
}
```

(This is based on [Mark Seemann's Resolving closed types](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/14/ResolvingClosedTypesWithMEF.aspx) article).

With that, should `C` actually look like:

```
public class C
{
  public C(B b)
  {

  }
}
```

You could have that closed type satisfied by an automatic creation of `B`:

```
var typeCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(MefAdapter<C>));
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new DirectoryCatalog("."), typeCatalog);

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

var c = container.ComposeExportedValue<C>();
// This instance of C should have a composed instance of B injected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, not without a reference to the instance of B...

If you had the reference you could call:

```
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instanceOfB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ServiceLocator in `class B` like this

```
class B
{
  private A a;

  B()
  {
    a = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<A>();
  }
}
```